# How can I tell if my edge is border or interior?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have an arbitrary collection of nodes connected by edges. I am trying to find a good way to tell if an edge/vertex is on the border or not.

The red nodes and blue lines are considered on border. Black lines and black nodes are considered interior.

[image]

All nodes are fixed to points on the Cartesian plane. It is a planar graph (no edges will cross over each other. They will intersect only at a node). Always one graph / connected shape in total (as opposed to multiple independently connected components).

Comment: Will your vertices always correspond to lattice points? If so, you could say that a vertex is interior iff it has degree 4. If not, I don't think there's a way to define the border/interior.

Comment: An "arbitrary collection of nodes connected by edges" is otherwise known as a graph. Is the graph planar, and are you given an embedding? If you're not given an embedding, there's no way to answer this question, because a graph may have multiple embeddings in which different nodes and edges are interior/exterior.

Comment: @DylanSp What do you mean by "always correspond to lattice points"?  It will look like a bunch of squares, yes. But as for degree four, look at the graph above, middle row, far right; those vertices have degree 4, do they not?

Comment: @TomvanderZanden What do you mean by embedding? It will always look something like the picture above (like a grid graph, or at least part of one), square-like structure. I don't know the formal terminology.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Okay I googled it. Yes it will be planar (no edges cross over each other; they always intersect at a node/vertex)

Comment: @user213846 Lattice points: $\{(x, y) | x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. You're right about degree 4 not being sufficient; Tom van der Zanden has the right approach.

Comment: @DylanSp Then yes, lattice points

Comment: @user213846 [Same graph, different embedding.](http://i.imgur.com/F6Huw8t.png) - it appears that in your problem each node has a given location (and these locations are grid points, even) but this is not standard for a graph.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I understand now, but yes in this case each node maps to a fixed point on the Cartesian plane.

Comment: So, we're not dealing with a general graph, but with a collection of squares. Do they always form one connected shape, or may there be multiple connected components? Please edit your question to clarify exactly what problem you're interested in.

Comment: One connected shape, yes.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify

Comment: You are looking for something like the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your set of points (but yours can be concave ;-)

Comment: This is plane geometry problem, not a graph-theoretic one. The solution depends on the data structure representing connections between nodes. Basically you need to find a first border node, and then for each border node - to find next one.